# Android OutOfMemoryError when Decoding a Bitmap

Tags: android, performance, out-of-memory, android-volley

Hello guys I am working on a project that uploads image file in the server. I am sending a data to the server using `Volley`. The Data that I will be sending contains `base64` string. I encountered **OutOfMemoryError** when I decoded an image file. Am I implementing it correctly? Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pathList.size(); i++) {
    //error occurred here 
         Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathList.get(i), options);
            Log.d("bitmapImage", "nisudSiya" + " " + image);
            encodedImage = UploadImageHelper.encodeImageBitmap(UploadImageHelper.scaleBitmap(image, 1000, 1000));
            stringUri.add(encodedImage);
        }
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, POST_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(CreatePostActivity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                VolleyApp.getInstance().cancelPendingRequests(PUSH_MULTIPLE_IMAGES);
                mProgressUpload.dismiss();
                finish();
                Log.d("tyler", response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(CreatePostActivity.this, "Error Uploading!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mProgressUpload.dismiss();
                Log.d("tagsdsad23", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                for (int i = 0; i < stringUri.size(); i++) {
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                    attachment.setType("image");
                    attachment.setUrl(stringUri.get(i));
                    shit.add(attachment);
                }
                Log.d("shitsize", String.valueOf(shit.size()));
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < shit.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                        Log.d("shittype", shit.get(i).getUrl());
                        jsonObject.put("type", shit.get(i).getType());
                        jsonObject.put("url", shit.get(i).getUrl());
                        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
                        Log.d("tyler-gwapa", jsonObject.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Log.d("tyler-gwapa", jsonArray.toString());

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(USER_TOKEN, userToken);
                params.put(CAPTION, postContent.getText().toString());
                params.put(ATTACHMENT, jsonArray.toString());
                return params;
            }
        };
        VolleyApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, PUSH_MULTIPLE_IMAGES_TAG);
```

Comment: image .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
compress image before you send to server ...!

Comment: I already did in:

encodedImage = UploadImageHelper.encodeImageBitmap(UploadImageHelper.scaleBitmap(image, 1000, 1000));

Comment: you are  encodedImage  image not compress ..! once you compress the image its reduce the size of image...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to compress bitmap and encode it.

```
 Bitmap selectedImage = getResizedBitmap(yourBitmaptoCompress, 350, 350);
```

Define getResizedBitmap method

```
 public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int bitmapWidth, int 
  bitmapHeight) {
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, 
   true);
}
```

Encode image bitmap (base64)

```
 String   encodedImage = encodeImage(selectedImage);
```

Define encodeImage Method

```
 private String encodeImage(Bitmap bm) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encImage;
}
```

Comment: Bitmap selectedImage = getResizedBitmap(selectedImage, 350, 350);

selectedImage is used twice?

Comment: the values of H and W which is 350, is it necessary to have 350? or how did u derived 350?

Comment: for more details, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object

Answer (score 0):

compress image before you send to server ...!

```
image .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
```

i hope its helpful to you ...!